# How does an adult become a Catholic?

Tags: catholicism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the requirements for a Protestant joining the Catholic church?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/requirements-for-a-protestant-joining-the-catholic-church)

So, a Protestant decides he wants to become a Catholic. What does she need to do?