# What are the steps for a non-Catholic Christian to become a Catholic?

Tags: catholicism, confession, conversion

What are the steps for a non-Catholic Christian to become a Catholic?

What is the process, and what does it entail?

1. What actions are incumbent upon such an aspirant?
2. Where does confession fit in?
3. How does the Church assist the candidate in overcoming obstacles like  family and friends who may not be supportive of the decision?

Comment: Hi Christian Teen. Your question is being closed because it's not clear what you are really asking here. It's best to only ask one question at once. If you want to know what is involved in becoming a Catholic if you are already some other kind of Christian, please edit the question to ask that. If you want to know what Catholic events you can participate in as a non-Catholic, please edit to ask that too.

Comment: As re-worded, this question is on topic (although likely too broad), but still a [duplicate](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/5117/20).

Comment: Disputing the *marked as duplicate* not all non-Catholic Christians are Protestants.

Comment: @FMS - That's splitting hairs a bit thin, but I'll leave it for another moderator to decide.

Comment: @DavidStratton Thank you for looking into it. Not sure if eastern orthodox (closeness) is different from other protestant and also between protestant may vary (e.g. depending on how RCC view the validity of the baptism). Perhaps the better [hold] is not specific on which non-Catholic Christian.

Comment: @ChristianTeen The type of *non-Catholic Christian* may need to be specified.

Comment: @ChristianTeen You may wish to ask another question regarding overcoming obstacles posed by family.

Comment: @FMS It is generally better to get the OP's approval before making substantial changes like that. (Because you can always ask a new question yourself.)